# Writing rspec tests for Chef test kitchen

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

I'm learning chef and working with kitchen. From the documentation I was able to figure out how to run bats tests, but I can't find any explanation on writing rspec tests other than that it is one of the four built in test suites.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your serverspec code under `test/integration/<suite name>/serverspec/<suite name>_spec.rb`. Make sure you load serverspec by putting this at the top of your file:

```
require 'serverspec'
set :backend, :exec
```

Other than that, just write normal serverspec test code.

Answer (score 1):

For integration tests check this tutorial about [serverspec](http://kitchen.ci/docs/getting-started/writing-server-test)

For Chef recipes unit testing use [ChefSpec](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec)